# How to use vertical bars "|" (pipes) in a title, header as a string?

Tags: pipe, typo3, ascii, letter

A page has the title "Systemadministrator (m/w) | Dresden". I use a vertical line (pipe) letter. When I render the title in typo3 (via dataWrap) it will only show "Systemadministrator (m/w)Dresden" (without the vertical line letter).

Is it possible to use the vertical line letter for titles, header, etc. without worrying that TYPO3 may interpret it as a Code (pipe)?

Answer (score 5):

The pipe symbol is used in TypoScript for [option split](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.1.0/view/3/1/). So you will have to escape this symbol. You can use `&#124;` and as far as I know this is also the only way, although it's kind of ugly to use such a HTML work a round.

Answer (score 1):

dataWrap automatically invokes stdWrap that uses pipe as a seperator, you should be able to use insertData instead, try changing:

```
MyObject.value.dataWrap = some stuff {page : title} some other stuff
```

to

```
MyObject.value = some stuff {page : title} some other stuff
MyObject.value.insertData = 1
```

see http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.6.0/view/1/5/#id2618446